# Cannot resolve method 'create' in 'LocationRequest'

Tags: java, android, gps

locationRequest=LocationRequest.create();
//create() function is not identify and i am using the latest version com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0 and but still getting this error please solve my query.

i am implement the gps enable and disable program in my android project

Answer (score 0):

```
private var fusedLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
                interval = getCaptureInterval() * 1000
                fastestInterval = getCaptureInterval() * 1000
                priority = Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
                maxWaitTime = getCaptureInterval() * 60 * 1000 // 10 minutes in milliseconds
                smallestDisplacement = 20f
            }

            fusedLocationProvider?.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper()
            )
        }
```

I am using this function to request location in my service class.

It is necessary to include this dependency in the Gradle file.

```
Implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
```

Note that `LocationRequest.create()` is deprecated. I'll update my response if I find a better way to do this.

Comment: brother thank for helping but i am writing in java and getting the same error

Comment: try the above answerd java code @Abhisek Patnaik , if it doesn't work can please post the screenshot of the error, it might help other developers to look into the issue

Comment: brother problem was fixed and i got it solution yesterday so now my  problem was fixed and i am not getting any error thank again brother  but many function are deprecated like create() function etc so anyone else solutions brother if you know then please tell

Comment: I am looking for  the same  to replace the deprecated code ,once i found for sure will let you know here in this comment , can you please exaplin  what fix you made  in your code here? so it will be help ful for all  developers

Answer (score 0):

**In Java**

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProvider;

fusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(getCaptureInterval() * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(getCaptureInterval() * 1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(getCaptureInterval() * 60 * 1000); // 10 minutes in milliseconds
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(20f);

    fusedLocationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When encountering the Exception:
`Cannot resolve method create in LocationRequest.`

It typically arises from utilizing the wrong class. In Android, there exist two classes with the name `LocationRequest`: one under `android.location` and the other under `com.google.android.gms.location`. If you're encountering this error, it's likely because you're using the first one. To resolve this issue, ensure that you're utilizing the correct `LocationRequest` class from `com.google.android.gms.location`.

**The Code:**

```java
LocationRequest locationRequest = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(10000)
        .setFastestInterval(5000);

LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addAllLocationRequests(Collections.singleton(locationRequest));
builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity())
        .checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
        try {
            LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Gps on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(requireActivity(), REQUEST_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                        break;
                    }
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your post is not an answer. If you have a question, ask a new question instead or edit your own one

Comment: i am using the second one its working now perfectly..